# Network analysis using closest facility

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I have two different point shapefiles and a road network. I have used closest facility to find shortest route between the two.

In the result section I have received only 143 lines; the remaining data was not processed. Please can anyone tell me the process how to get the total result.

Comment: I added the ArcGIS-desktop tag because you mentioned network-analyst, which is an ArcGIS extension. If that's not the software you're using, please [edit] your question to add the correct tag.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you please provide a few more details about what you've tried so far, and where you are having difficulties? For example, a screenshot of the input you are giving your tool? Or more details about what your are expecting to see instead of 143 lines? You might also find the introductory GIS SE tour useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour